# Matching something or the end of the content

Tags: python, regex

How can I ask to look for a word followed by `%`, this special character being optional if the word is at the end of the text to analyze ?

The following code prints only `showme` but I would also like to have `metoo`.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import re

p = re.compile(r"(?<!@)\w+(?=%)")

for m in p.finditer(r"@hideme showme% metoo"):
    print(m.group())
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. What would you like to have if you have the string `@hideme showme% youfirst metoo`? Would it be `showme` and `metoo` or `showme` and `youfirst`?

Comment: Indeed, the answer of Madison May does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple look for \% OR $ (the end of text char).

`p = re.compile(r"(?<!@)\w+(?=%|$)")`

Comment: No need to escape `%`.

Comment: I've tried this without success. Maybe the updated of my python code was not made when I've laucnhed it. Thanks for this.

Comment: maybe it was an issue with a *.pyc file or something?